# jQuery radialIndicator auto (without refreshing page) based on value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using [jQuery radialIndicator](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/radialIndicator.html).

As you can see the function will run after page loaded. But now if I have data from database and I want it show live without refreshing the page. How to do that?

Here is the code:

JS

```
$(function () {
    var getVal = $('#get').html();

    var radialObj7 = $('#indicatorContainer7').radialIndicator({
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 1250
    }).data('radialIndicator').animate(getVal); //to get the value
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="prg-cont rad-prg" id="indicatorContainer7"><div id="get"><?php include('load.php'); ?></div></div>
```

PHP(load.php)

```
700
```

JS Autorefresh

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval
(
    function ()
    {
        $('#get').load('load').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 1000
);
```

I tried above my code, the value is auto update but the indicator not change based on value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you need to add animation on every interval then there must be some logic in PHP code so that every time you get a new value from server side, which reflects your UI and you will get animation.

Also, you have to update Indicator value every time when an AJAX call made(use `load.php` instead of `load` only ) like,

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
    $('#get').load('load.php',function(val){// load.php instead of load
        // change value in callback
        $('#indicatorContainer7').data('radialIndicator').animate(val); 
    }).fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I tried but no effect. Where I need to put that code?

Comment: Hi Rohan, if you're still online, I would like to ask 1 more question. How to set maxValue automatic from autorefresh too?

Comment: You can set it by using Setter method like `$('#indicatorContainer7').data('radialIndicator').option('maxValue',500); ` Read more from http://ignitersworld.com/lab/radialIndicator.html#documentation

Comment: I add it but not working, $('.getIndicator'+element.lineName).data('radialIndicator').option('ma‌​xValue',500).animate(element.runningQuantity).maxValue;

Comment: show me your html with the class name you've used in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141357/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-rohan-kumar).